# Configuration Database baseline - //CheckDifferentData('cpu', OGActualDataRow, OGDataRows);

Tags: objectgears

I have created have downloaded Configuration database from https://www.objectgears.eu/it-configuration-database and created CMDB baseline according to the example https://doc.objectgears.cz/vcd/en-US/case-study-record-baseline-solution-implementation/v/1.9.0.0.
`//CheckDifferentData('cpu', OGActualDataRow, OGDataRows);`

However, only CPU difference is highlighted with the background colour, not RAM or aother columns. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly created rule for the *cpu* column. You have to create equivalent rules also for the other columns that yu want to check - one for each of them. Then you apply the same steps also for other entities - see printscreens on https://www.objectgears.cz/configuration-management

CMDB Configuration items from various layers are described in https://doc.objectgears.cz/vcd/en-US/a_configuration_mngt